# htaccess disallow redirect specific subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, virtual

I redirect all virtual subdomains as follows.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^$  subdomain.php?url=%1  [NC,QSA,L]
```

This way, I get data from the database. All "virtual subdomains". But there is a real subdomain. Opencart inside (shop.mysite.com)

htaccess directs this as well. How do I prevent it from just redirecting the word "shop".

My Full Code:

```
Options Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
directoryindex index.php
Options -indexes
RewriteRule index index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^$  subdomain.php?url=%1  [NC,QSA,L]

# www.site.com  >>  site.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: _Aside:_ Your rule only matches the document root; is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mysite\.com$
> RewriteRule ^$  subdomain.php?url=%1  [NC,QSA,L]
> ```

You can add another condition to exclude the `shop` subdomain. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^shop\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ subdomain.php?url=%1  [QSA,L]
```

The `!` prefix negates the regex, so the *condition* is successful when it does not match.

OR, you could use a negative lookahead in your original condition regex. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!shop\.).+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ subdomain.php?url=%1  [QSA,L]
```

However, your directives are also in the wrong order. Your external redirect to remove the `www` subdomain should appear first, otherwise you need to incorporate another exception into the above rule.

For example:

```
Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule index index.php

# www.site.com  >>  site.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^shop\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ subdomain.php?url=%1  [QSA,L]
```

You were also adding the `Indexes` option, only to remove it again with a later directive.